# Is it bad practice to return Enums in Java?

Tags: java, enums

Lets say I have a class to model an item in a game like so:

```
public class Item {
    private final EnumItem type;
    
    public Item(EnumItem type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
        
    public Item(String name) {
        this.type = EnumItem.fromName(name);
    }
}

public enum EnumItem {
    MACHINE_GUN("machine_gun"),
    SWORD("sword"),
    BAT("bat"),
    DEFAULT("default");
    
    private final String name;
    
    public EnumItem(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public static EnumItem fromName(String name) {
        for(EnumItem i: EnumItem.values()) {
            if(i.name.equals(name)) {
                return i;
            } else {
                return EnumItem.DEFAULT;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assume that `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` of `Item` are overridden correctly to compare the internal Enum.

Now I want a way to distinguish these items with a getter in `Item`: should I return an `Enum` or the `String` name? Is it good practice to return an `Enum` in general? Or is there a better way to distinguish these `Item`s? Because returning the enum kind of looks like exposing the rep to me and I don't want my colleagues to use `EnumItem` directly to compare `Item`s.

The approaches I thought of are the following:

1. `string getName()` to do something like `item1.getName().equals("machine_gun")`;
2. `EnumItem getEnum()` to do `item1.getEnum().equals(EnumItem.MACHINE_GUN)`;
3. `item1.equals(new Item("machine_gun"))`;
4. `static name(String name) { new Item(name) }` to do `item1.equals(Item.name("machine_gun"))`;

I don't know what should I do, I'd appreciate some insight from experienced programmers.

I know they look like they would from context, but in my use case these items have no special functionality that would justify extending from the base Item class.

Comment: It is fine to return enums and it makes sense in this use case since your item looks like a value object

Comment: Why did you implement `fromName()`? Doesn't the standard enum method `valueOf(String name)` work for you? It also seems very unusual to have a default in an enum.

Comment: @jarmod `valueOf(String name)`, name here isn't the name of the Enum not name in the enum?

Comment: What do you mean with _"returning the enum kind of looks like exposing the rep to me"_?

Comment: If the thing you are trying to represent is best modelled by an arbitrary-length immutable sequence of characters, return a String. Otherwise, return an instance of a more specific class - remember, enums are just special classes.

Comment: @AndyTurner I think yours is a good take, it's the kind of questions I'd like to ask myself when designing

Comment: @MarkRotteveel in other parts of my code I've avoided returning e.g. List<SomeClass> in favor of returning classes that contain Lists and that have methods that better suit my needs and I was wondering if there was any problem in returning an Enum from a code quality standpoint

Comment: It is still not clear what "rep" in "exposing the rep" means. Do you mean something like the internals or implementation-specific aspects?

Answer (score 1):

Is this good practice? Sure, you're using aggregation since Item doesn't depend on EnumItem, which is fine. That being said, could it be done better? Sure. Is the alternative I provide the only solution? No.

**Alternative**

If you want this to be extensible, consider using an interface to represent an item. Then allow the interface to extend this interface to provide some standard types. Alternatively you could use composition or aggregation to define a type inside EnumItem that implements the Item interface to ensure that equals/hashcode for the Item are always override and adhere to some contract.

```java
interface Item {

    String key();

}

enum EnumItem implement Item {

    private final String key;

    EnumItem(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return key;
    }

}

class AbstractItem implements Item {
    
    // constructor, override name()
    
}
```

```java
Item item = EnumItem.FOO_BAR;

Item item2 = new AbstractItem("FooBar");

Item item3 = () -> "FooBar";
```

Comment: This won't compile - `name()` is final method

Comment: I like this approach because, even though it doesn't really fit my use case specifically (the sole reason is that I'm implementing a specification I have been given by my professor that doesn't contemplate the future possibility of adding extra items), I reckon I could use this pattern in the future

Comment: @DuncG I believe this WILL compile as afaik final attributes are final once you initialise them in the constructor

Comment: @blvck_mvgic_dot_exe The method in EnumItem above won't compile as `name()`, but would be OK if changed to something else such as `getName()` as you've used in your question.

Comment: Yeah that is a good point, my apologies, I forgot that Enum had a method already called name, woopsies. Great job noticing that!